Why can't I open Play Store through Appium Inspector?
I'm trying to automate opening the Play Store using Appium Inspector with the following JSON capabilities:
{
     "platformName": "Android",
     "appium:platformVersion": "14.0",
     "appium:deviceName": "Pixel 6a",
     "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
     "appium:appPackage": "com.android.vending",
     "appium:appActivity": "com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity",
     "appium:noReset": true   
} 

However, when I launch the Play Store via Appium, it doesn't open, even though the logs indicate that the AssetBrowserActivity activity was started
Additional info:

Android 14.0
Emulator: Pixel 6a
Appium: using UiAutomator2
Appium logs show a successful connection to the device, but the Play Store doesn't appear.

Any help or advice on configuring the capabilities correctly to automate the Play Store would be greatly appreciated.
If I manually launch the Play Store through the emulator, it works fine. What could be causing Appium Inspector to fail to open the Play Store correctly?
